# JOIN vs multiple queries when there is LIMIT 5

Tags: php, mysql, preferences

I have two tables like below:

```
// posts
+----+---------+------------------+-----------+
| id |  title  |      content     | author_id |
+----+---------+------------------+-----------+
| 1  | title1  | content1         | 123       |
| 2  | title2  | content2         | 456       |
| .  | .       | .                | .         |
| .  | .       | .                | .         |
| .  | .       | .                | .         |
+----+---------+------------------+-----------+

// users
+----+-------+
| id |  name |
+----+-------+
| 1  | Jack  |
| 2  | Peter |
| .  | .     |
| .  | .     |
| .  | .     |
+----+-------+
```

I want to select 5 posts like below:

```
SELECT * FROM posts WHERE 1 ORDER BY id LIMIT 5
```

I also need to get the name of *author* for each post. So I can do that by using a `JOIN` like this:

```
SELECT p.*, u.name
FROM posts p
JOIN users ON p.author_id = u.id
WHERE 1
ORDER BY id
LIMIT 5
```

I can do that the other way like this:

```
SELECT * FROM posts WHERE 1 ORDER BY id LIMIT 5
// storing results in a PHP array named $results
foreach( $results as $result ) {
    SELECT name FROM users WHERE id =  $result['author_id']
    // storing results in a PHP array named $names
}
// combining $names and $results to make expecting result
```

---

So, which approach is more efficient for huge dataset? In other word, Does `JOIN` happen before `LIMIT`? if yes, then I guess doing that by PHP would be faster, am I wrong?

Answer (score 1):

An engine can specify its own implementation, but MySQL will not read through the entire table: it will do `LIMIT` at the same time as the `JOIN`, fetching line by line until it has found 5 lines.

Comment: @stack Thanks for the +1, but remember that you can accept an answer if it has properly answered your question. :)

Answer (score 0):

MySQL Engine: **InnoDB** uses the row level locking in table then **LIMIT** will work at the same time as the **JOIN**, fetching line by line until it has found 5 lines.